# Float page at bottom of window while maintaining relative position div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Someone helped me implement a website where I have a center div that is pushed out of the screen by divs on the left, right, bottom and top. Try clicking on the right left eye to get an example. The structure of the page is as follows:

### HTML

```
    <div id="fullContainer">

        <div id="right">

        </div>
        <div id="left">

        </div>  
        <div id="top">

        </div>
        <div id="bottom">

        </div>
    </div>


<div id="centerContainer">
    <div id="relativeContainer">
        <div id="content" class="center">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
        body{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        #centerContainer {
            width:50%;
            margin:0 auto;
            height:0;
        }
        #relativeContainer {
            position:relative;
        }
        #fullContainer {
            background-color:#c6421f;
            position:fixed;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            bottom:0;

        }
        #content {
            margin: 0 auto;
            position:relative;
            left:0;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            transition: all 0.9s ease;
        }
        #content.right {
            left:-1150px;
        }
        #content.left {
            left:1150px;
        }
        #content.bottom {
            top:-300px;
        }
        #content.top {
            top:1100px;
        }

        #content div {
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        #header{
                opacity:0.6;
                color: beige;
                font-family: 'Dosis',sans-serif;
                font-size: 42px;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align: center;     
        }
        #left {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:-1800px;
            height:100%;
            width:1750px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            transition: all 0.9s ease;
        }

        #left.opened {
            left:0;
        }
        #left-content{
            margin-left:70px;
            position:relative;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            transition: all 0.9s ease;
        }

        #right {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            right:-1800px;
            height:100%;
            width:1800px;
            overflow:auto;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            transition: all 0.9s ease;



        }

        #right.opened {
            right:0;
        }
        #resume img{
            float: right;
            margin:0 auto;
            width:50%;

        }


        #top {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: -1100px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 1000px;
            background: #c6421f;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            transition: all 0.9s ease;

        }
        #top.opened {
            top:0;
        }
        #bottom {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            bottom:-125px;
            width:100%;
            height:100px;
            background:red;
            border:1px solid #444;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.9s ease;
            transition: all 0.9s ease;
        }
        #bottom.opened {
            bottom:0;
        }
```

My question is how can I modify this so the content div sinks to the bottom of the page. Everything I try seems to make another part of the webpage function incorrectly.

Here is the actual page: http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/ - it sits at the bottom of my screen but on bigger screens it starts to float to the top

Comment: I think I figured it out - I ended up setting a div inside of content as bottom:0; position:fixed;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add/change your #content div to have:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

and remove left:0;

I believe that is the effect you're looking for.

Comment: p.s. what's/is there a reason behind maintaining relative position?

Comment: try clicking the left eye and you should see why adding that doesn't fix - the relative position is to allow the center div to slide out of the screen - right now with position:fixed it makes it so the div doesnt slide out of the frame. click the right eye and see what i mean - thanks mike

Comment: If you add the above code to the div with the id #content then it should still slide out. You'll have to up the amount it slides left a bit more, somewhere like left: 1500 to make sure it slides all the way off.

Just updated it a bit as well, to remove that left:0;